# Headphone Jack Detection Mechanism?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, speakers, headphones

I am trying to build a circuit that turns on a speaker when headphones are unplugged (so it like how our phones detect when our headphones are connected).

To do this, I was thinking of simply using a headphone socket and male jack. This way, when the male jack is plugged, the circuit between the positive and negative terminals of the socket is open (as shown in the picture), and the speaker will not have any power. However, when the male jack is unplugged, the circuit is closed, and the speaker will turn on.

[image]

The problem with this design is that I would like to be able to easily pull the male jack out, at angles. However, the problem with only using a female headphone socket is that the headphones can't be pulled out at an angle, but rather can only be pulled out straight. To solve this problem, I was thinking of attaching a dongle (aka headphone extension wire) to the fixed socket, and then plugging the headphones into that dongle. Now, I can pull the male jack freely, at whatever angle (since the dongle is free to rotate).

Dongle/extension:

[image]

However, the problem with doing *that* is that now, the socket's circuit is permanently open since the dongle is always plugged in and won't be removed. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can overcome this problem? Any suggestions or solutions to what I am trying to do? Please let me know if I should explain more details. Thanks!

Comment: Just get an audio connector that has a fourth tip switch connection. That's what it's designed for.
https://www.cui.com/blog/understanding-audio-jack-switches-and-schematics

Comment: You can then use it to drive a relay to route audio signal around:
https://www.embedded.com/print/4015894

Comment: Can this "audio connector that has a fourth tip switch connection" handle insertion of the jack at different angles? Because **that** is what is being requested.

Comment: Could the OP clarify what they mean by "different angles" with regards to insertion and extraction? Because ultimately it sits in a cylindrical channel unless the OP has something mechanically different in mind.

Comment: I don't know of wire-to-wire jack switches. Maybe make a tiny PCB with the only the board-to-wire jack switch (the first drawing), cut the female side of the headphone extension wire and solder the PCB at that end? Or even hardwire the jacket without PCB. With hot glueing the PCB, applying one or several heatshrinks, and lots of craftmanship you could make a decent looking bulky 'connector'.

Comment: Hi Toor, I've seen that website, but my question was about using switches when using an extension cable. The circuits shown on the website only use a single male audio jack that is plugged and unplugged. However, what I wanted to do was keep an extension male jack permanently plugged in, and then plug my headphones to the extension, and have the circuit detect my headphones that way.

Comment: So my comment about different angles isn't very important. Rather, I just wanted to explain why I would want to permanently keep the extension plugged in (try to unplug headphones from your phone while tugging on the wire at an angle).

Comment: Huisman, I think cutting the female jack would work! I just wanted to possibly try using socket components so it can be used for another purpose (and soldering such small wires well might be difficult).